# interface GList with type E to extend class ListMap with types K and V

Tags: java, list, generics

I want my interface GList with type E to extend class ListMap with types K and V.
I am trying to use

```
public interface GList<E extends ListMap<K, V>> {

}
```

but it gives compile time error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't refer to `K` and `V` in `ListMap<K, V>` if you don't declare them first.

You have to declare all 3 type parameters:

```
public interface GList<K, V, E extends ListMap<K, V>> 
{
}
```

To implement the interface:

```
public class GNil<K, V, E extends ListMap<K, V>> implements GList<K, V, E>
{ 
}
```

Comment: but doesn't it add 3 type parameters to GList?
because I tried implementing GList but again stuck with parameters.
    
public class GNil<E implements GList<E>>{

}

Comment: @SakshiAgarwal Yes, it defines 3 type parameters in the GList interface. You can't use a type parameter if you don't define it first. `public class GNil<K, V, E extends ListMap<K, V>> implements GList<K, V, E>{ }`